# Exporting from Google Spreadsheet to Firebase, ERROR

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

I think most of my errors come from the updates of Firebase. But I'm getting there.

Still loving Firebase!

Ok, I'm trying to export a column demo Spreadsheet to Firebase (code bellow). The error seems to be related to the Firebase reference. I know how to fix it in my Firebase projects, but this is hooked into the Script editor of the spreadsheet.

> ERROR: ReferenceError: "FirebaseApp" is not defined. (line 13, file
>   "export")

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = 

SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rV2_S2q5rcakOuHs2E1iLeKR2floRIozSytAt2iRXo8");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var year = data[i][0];
    dataToImport[year] = {
    caption:data[i][1]
  };
}

 var firebaseUrl = "https://test-db-9833d.firebaseio.com/";

 // ERROR HERE ********************************************

 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
 base.setData("", dataToImport);

}
```

Comment: Did you install FirebaseApp in your spreadsheet? You can instructions here: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

Answer (score 3):

Following is the right answer:
In the script there is a resources tab to add a library:
Search:
**MYeP8ZEEt1ylVDxS7uyg9plDOcoke7-2l**
and choose 11-static
then rerun your script

documentation:
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

Comment: Add some proper description

Answer (score 0):

for Google Sheets to be able to write to your Firebase instance, there can be a couple of reasons that you can't write to it, check this:

- did you give sheet permission to access your Google account info and Docs
- did you reference the firebase database url correctly
- did you loosen permissions on firebase, for testing perposes you can give writing `true`,  just to see if that works for start, and then use full perm setup
- did you tried to use debugging tool like `Logger.log` to see what you get in log on specific sections of code?

also I have been able to record full screencast of my process and you can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SIAnjgKZZQ&feature=youtu.be

here is the code that I changed to use `dinamic` header titles for labels for our data and not have it "hardcoded" way :)

```
function onfire() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var allvals = []; var row = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++ ){
      if( values[i][j] ) {
        row[ values[0][j].toString() ] = values[i][j] ;
      }
    }
    allvals.push( row ); // insert row
    row = {}; // blank template obj
  }
  var firebaseUrl = "https://my-android-app-demo1.firebaseio.com/sheet";
  var base = firebase.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, sec);
  // Logger.log( allvals );
  base.setData("", allvals );
}
```

hth, kres

Comment: Cool, will check out this evening. Have been on the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain JavaScript, initialize your `FirebaseApp` class as follows:

```
// Load Firebase library 
var firebaseScript = document.createElement('script');
firebaseScript.setAttribute('src', 
    'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.1/firebase.js');
document.head.appendChild(firebaseScript);

// Initialize Firebase
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
};

var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Alternatively, if you use Webpack or Browserify, you can install `firebase` package and then initialize it as follows:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");

var config = {
  // ...
};

var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```